# How does electric potential relate to mean curvature?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, potential-theory, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider a compact, convex domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with $|\Omega|=1$ with smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$.

Now consider the electric potential generated by this uniform mass distribution: $\phi = \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dx$. 
**Question:** I would like to know if there is a relationship between mean curvature $H$ and $\phi$. What I have in mind is an inequality of the form
$\|\phi - \bar \phi\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)} \leq C \|H - \bar H\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}$ where $\bar \phi$ and $\bar H$ denote the averages over $\partial \Omega$ of $\phi$ and $H$ respectively and $p$ can be anything for the time being.

Although one term is much more 'non-local' than the other, for a convex body it seems reasonable that the closer to being an surface of constant mean curvature, the closer one is to being an equipotential surface. This is related to a previous question of mine which ended up going unanswered regarding whether the only convex, compact equipotential surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ was a sphere or not.

Comment: I have no time to look for a precise reference, but this belongs to the general theory of rearrangement in PDEs. Reliable authors are Talenti, Bandle and perhaps Mossino.

Comment: Isn't $\phi$ infinite along the boundary of $\Omega$?

Comment: No. It's like integrating 1/r in R^3 which will give you something of order 1 since surface measure is r^2

Comment: A more elaborate way of seeing this is that the characteristic function of $\Omega$ is an $L^p$ function for all $p \in [1,\infty]$ and standard elliptic theory says that $\phi$ must be $H^2$ so in fact continuous.

Comment: In the statement of your question, you have the $L_p$ norm of $\phi$ along the boundary of $\Omega$. I still think it's infinite there. Your replies seem to be talking about the $L_p$ norm of $\phi$ on $\R^3\backslash\Omega$.

Comment: $\phi$ is a continuous function and so bounded

Comment: OK. I see where I might have gotten this wrong.

Comment: Isn't this problem related to the capacitor problem? Have a look at Sections 11.15-11.17 of the book "Analysis" of E. H. Lieb and M. Loss (2nd. edition), or the book "Function Spaces and Potential Theory" by D. R. Adams and L. I. Hedberg. 

Comment: Thanks for the reference Pedro. However the capacity problem seems to be to prescribe fixed boundary data on a domain $\Omega$ and consider $\phi$ to be *harmonic*. I am considering $-\Delta \phi = 1_{\Omega}$ which I think is quite different. 

Comment: Suppose your domain is uniformly convex, and you run a (volume normalized) mean curvature flow.  By the results of N. Sesum, ("Rate of convergence of the mean curvature flow." Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 61 (2008), no. 4, 464–485), the metric on the surface of the domain converges exponentially fast to that of the sphere.  If you are close a sphere, you should be able to control the quantity of the potential.  And presumably, you could integrate in time the mean curvature and your potential function to get some sort of control.

Comment: Right but this will only say how the potential converges to a constant potential under the mean curvature flow. It won't give a general relation between the two quantities in question I believe.

Comment: is the inequality homogeneous under scaling?  the example of a long and thin rod with two capped ends seems to be a good one to consider.

Comment: Just come by my office whenever you're back at Courant. I'll be at the bagel breakfast this morning if you're around.

Answer (score 1):

This seems very related to the Eshelby / Polya-Szegö conjecture, which asks (in one of its formulations, see [Liu](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=2008&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=pubyear&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Liu&s5=&s6=&s7=Eshelby&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)) whether the fact that the solutions of
$$
\Delta \phi = 1_\Omega 
$$
(plus appropriate decay at infinity) are of the form 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d a_k x_k^d +C \textrm{ in } \Omega
$$
implies that the $\Omega$ is a ball, or an ellipsoid. This property is true in dimension 2 and 3, but it is also known to be extremely unstable, see e.g. [Kang](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167663609000131).

And what you are asking would imply stability, I think.